# ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[33694,33694] and type float on:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to run my training file and this error pops up. My data dimensions are 4190 by 33694. I tried to reduce the batch size, but still it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to allocate a tensor of size 4.2GB (=33694*33694*4/1024^3). Another tensor of the same size would be allocated during backprop. Even if your network has only a single (fully-connected?) layer you would probably need 12GB of video memory to run it.

You will have to review your design, there is hardly any way around it. Replace FC layers with something different, reduce number of neurons drastically, rescale your date if possible.

Comment: i tried it on the 22gb gpu as well. but the same error pops up.

Comment: you need at least 12gb to train with this single layer, the rest of your network probably needs memory too